# Hide a class after a specific id with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, class

i have a problem with this code:

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div id="hi"></div>
<span>Hello my friend</span>
<font>Hola!</font>
<div id="break">
   <div></div>
</div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

What i want is hide all div with class "test" after div with id "hi".
How can i do?

Thanks.

Comment: Where's the code you're having problems with?

Comment: I have not posted because I do not know how to do it, however, I was thinking something like this: $('.test').nextAll('#hi').hide();

Comment: Should the div hide on a click event or on page load?

Comment: @LorenzoBelfanti: You were close. As a rule of thumb, the target for every method is it's left.

Comment: Give a man a fish blablabla... : http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with CSS :

```
#id ~ .text{
    display:none;
}
```

But this is a CSS3 selector. If you want something supported by older browser, you can use this jQuery :

```
$('#hi').nextAll('.test').hide();
```

Note that pure CSS is always the preferred methods over JS (if there is a choice). So try avoiding JS if your code is simply used to hide elements.

## Reference

- [General sibling selector (~)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)
- [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)
- [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

---

## Edit

After checking the support table of `~`, ie7 and newer support it, so there is probably no compatibility problem (who still support ie6?!).

If you need to use Javascript, `$('#id ~ .test')` will be faster than `$('#id').nextAll('.test');` (in browsers that support `.querySelectorAll()` at least).

Comment: I like learning new things. This should be an accepted answer. +1 from me :). [See working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ce511sds/).

Answer (score 4):

You were close in your comment, but it's the other way around

```
$('#hi').nextAll('.test').hide();
// start from #hi then select all next elements that have class test
```